# How can i solve this errors and convert types?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, fragment

I am a beginner in android programing. I want to write a program with fragment, i read this tutorial(http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-fragment-example.html) and write that but when i run the program, the program has compiler errors! 
The errors are about add() and replace() functions.

I write AndroidFragmentActivity class in below, Please read this and help me.

AndoridFragmentActivity.java:

```
package com.appfragmentarray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.util.Log;

import com.appfragmentarray.ListFragment.OnURLSelectedListener;

public class AndroidFragmentActivity extends Activity implements OnURLSelectedListener{
     boolean detailPage = false;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Log.v("AndroidFragmentActivity", "onCreate()");
  Log.v("AndroidFragmentsavedInstanceState", savedInstanceState == null ? "true" : "false");

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  if(savedInstanceState == null) {
   android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ListFragment listFragment = new ListFragment();
   ft.add(R.id.displayList, listFragment, "List_Fragment");
   ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
   ft.commit();
  }

  if(findViewById(R.id.displayDetail) != null){
   detailPage = true;
   getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

   DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayDetail);
   if(detailFragment == null){
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.displayDetail, detailFragment, "Detail_Fragment1");
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.commit();
   }
  }

 }


 public void onURLSelected(String URL) {
  Log.v("AndroidFragmentActivity",URL);

  if(detailPage){
   DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment)
   getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayDetail);
   detailFragment.updateURLContent(URL);
  }
  else{
   DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
   detailFragment.setURLContent(URL);
   android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.replace(R.id.displayList, detailFragment, "Detail_Fragment2");
   ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
   ft.addToBackStack(null);
   ft.commit();
  }
 }


  }
```

The errors are:

> Cannot cast from Fragment to DetailFragment
>
> The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction
>   is not applicable for the arguments (int, ListFragment, String)
>
> The method replace(int, Fragment, String) in the type
>   FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int,
>   DetailFragment, String)

How can i solve this problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably mixing up the [compatibility Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html) and the normal 3.0+ [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) classes.

If you want to use the compatibility package:

Make `AndroidFragmentActivity` extend `FragmentActivity`

Change

```
android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

to

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

and make sure all calls to `getFragmentManager()` are instead `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Make sure your Fragments extend from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`

**OR**

If you want to use the normal Fragments, get rid of all the `support.v4` imports and make sure that your Fragments work with `android.app.Fragment`, which is the non-comptability Fragment.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Do you mean, i should import support.v4.app or import support.app for supportFragmentManager() and add() and etc not both of tehm ? This is true?

Comment: @NiceNICE `supportFragmentManager()` and `add()` are *methods* part of the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction` *class* which you already imported. Simply make sure that you now call `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. The `add()` method is the same and make sure you extend `FragmentActivity` if you're in Eclipse press `ctrl + shift + O` to fix imports.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManger() is for android 3+. This is true? If i declare minsdkVersion=9 in manifest file, what will happen if the program run on device with android 2.3? (I import android.support.v4.app not android.app).

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManger()` is for 3.0+ **and** below 3.0. You should look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html) tutorial, it shows how to use the support library. So if you use `getSupportFragmentManger()`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing support library (v4) fragments with native fragments.  Make sure ALL your fragments and related components are using v4.  For example, your activity should be extending `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.  Make sure your `ListFragment` and `DetailFragment` also use v4 and not the native Fragments.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please answer another question in up comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

we should be sure if we are using compatibility or normal fragments, either android.support.v4.app.* or android.app.*

I am using `android.support.v4.app.*`  and

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

and it works well for me..